# What is this logical fallacy called?

Tags: fallacies

You made mistakes in the past, but learned from them and now you are not committing these mistakes any longer.
However, because you committed these mistakes in the past, some might say, that you are morally not in the position to point out these very mistakes to others.

How is this fallacy called?

Comment: The issue describe is the person who did the mistake in the past & that same person is NOW correcting other people or teaching other people how to avoid the mistake is simply being called a hypocrite.  This is not an outright fallacy. A fallacy has to be an argument which has a conclusion.  Now when you reject my argument & my conclusion because of my past mistakes that can be a FALLACY: the attack of the person (ad hominem). This fallacy is frequently misunderstood & claimed to be committed where there is no conclusion. Just calling people names is not enough.

Comment: A hypocrite in my understanding would be: Person A is blaming Person B for instance for some kind of misbehavior while in the same time Person A is exactly showing the same misbehavior like Person B. In my example Person A is not misbehaving any longer. The logical error: Person B says: You are morally not  in the position to point this misbehavior out to me, because you committed it by yourself in the past. OK, that could be an (ad hominem).

Comment: your definition implies only negative behaviour. Any inconsistent act with your actions & your verbal communication would qualify as a hypocrite. A drill instructor cannot be seen correctly if he is yelling at a recruit about his wrinkled uniform while the drill instructor's uniform is wrinkled. The image of the person teaching has to be positive & not inconsistent. A English professor making constant grammar errors would be horrible. A math teacher constantly making Mathematical errors is looks bad. This is more of a psychological issue than logical.

Comment: What makes the difference between the psychological issue and the logical issue is that person B MUST REJECT YOUR CONCLUSION because of your character. Be sure the rejection is only your character and not your premises to your argument. If you have no argument like I said there is no fallacy. Fallacy implies there are premises and a conclusion. Someone rejecting what you say as in a group because they don't like you or your past behavior is NOT a fallacy in itself. There is no argument in the last variation. So that is a psychological issue.

Comment: Konrad Adenauer, first chancellor of the Federal Republic of Germany: "What do I care about the nonsense I talked yesterday".

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: @Logikal The demarcation between psychological and logical is blurred in informal argumentation. Rhetoric, which utilizes ethos, pathos, and logos, frequently employs informal logical fallacy. See [Toulmin's model of argumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Toulmin#The_Toulmin_model_of_argument) for more details. In other words, informal fallacies largely rely on cognitive biases.

Comment: @JD, the point I was expressing was without rejection of a conclusion separates philosophy from Psychology. All rational arguments are formal. Formal in the sense that the reasoning is a PATTERN. A pattern that has been done so many times it is recognizable. As a result we give those recognized patterns a name. Just because someone disrespected another person does not mean a fallacy has occurred. That is why I stated that people call out ad hominem the first chance they get which is wrong. Fallacies are about bad arguments not emotional effects.

Comment: @Logikal You are confusing the lay definition of formal with the more technical term. Argumentation theory roughly divides [arguments and fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Informal_fallacies into formal and informal). That's just a fact, and your idiosyncratic terminology just creates confusion. It's obvious that the implicit premise of the OP is "you're advice is hypocritical because you ONCE...", then there is an argument. I'll supplement my answer to clarify for you the argument.

Comment: @JD, we agree in concept IF THERE IS AN ACTUAL ARGUMENT. We must also be certain the OP is having his conclusion of his argument rejected because of his past mistakes OR IS HE BEING DISCRIMINATED AGAINST.  The two things are not the same. I want to make sure the conclusion is being rejected because of the person. The op does not make that 100 percent clear. We can all agree the fallacy is there if the argument exists and is rejected because of who the OP is and his past. Often people perceive arguments out of nothing and cry ad hominem! It is not supposed to be there for one's beck and call.

Comment: @Logikal With due respect, because it's not clear to you, doesn't mean that the OP isn't clear. Nor can natural language ever be 100% clear. See [ambiguity of natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity). Since at least later Ludwig Wittgenstein, it has become indefensible to suggest that all meaning is contained in text. See [implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) for the current state of the relationship between meaning and context.

Comment: See [language-game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)) for more information on LW's contribution which now undergirds a substantial body of philosophy and linguistics. Granted, there are people such as tyros in a domain and those with ASD who have problems decoding intention, but we needn't concern ourselves with the exceptions to recognize the rule.

Comment: @JD, sorry to disagree here bit you seem to be more into Rhetoric than the logic here. I deal with deductive reasoning. This reasoning deliberately reduces the emotional aspects of Rhetoric. The argument should be rewritten into proper logical form not taken as is. Secondly, the job of the person sending communications HAS THE BURDEN OF BEING CLEAR AND CONSISE not the reader. The reader might make a mistake. You seem to make an excuse to the person making the communication. It is not olay to just argue any kind of way. This is the part you are not getting. This is about patterns of reasoning.

Comment: @Logikal Because I disagree you doesn't mean I don't understand your position. I simply disagree. Human beings, except in rare cases such as proof and model theory, don't do deduction in argumentation. That's just a fact that anyone who has taken a class on argumentation can see. I suggest you take an intro course in argumentation such as [that of David Zarefsky of Northwestern University](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/argumentation-the-study-of-effective-reasoning-2nd-edition.html).

Comment: @JD, that professor is a professor of RHETORIC.  I did study Rhetoric before as well so the course is not needed. Arguments are not defined the same in philosophy and rheroric. You should know that. There are many subjects that frequently use the term argument & logic all in a different context: philosophy,  psychology, rhetoric, law, mathematics, & computer science. Too many people are either not aware the terminology differs or perhaps they just don't care about the distinctions. I do not use the terminology incorrectly. You are using the wrong context & subject field if you think that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113791/discussion-between-j-d-and-logikal).

Answer (score 1):

This is an informal fallacy whereby an opponent attempts to undermine your argument by arguing that you are a hypocrite. It could be viewed as a [poisoning the well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well) or a [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man). In the former case, in essence, by alienating the listener to you personally by claiming you are guilty of [hypocrisy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocrisy), the opponent hopes to shift the focus of attention away from the argument to your credibility. Of course, it's a fallacy because hypocrisy requires that you must currently be engaged in said action, belief, activity, etc, or that there isn't a [false equivalency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence) between what you do and say because of subtle but important differences. The straw man might come into play if your opponent misrepresents your position by conflating your past position for your current one.

**But the best fit for the name of this fallacy is called the [whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism) a subspecies of [tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque).** From WP:

> Whataboutism, also known as whataboutery, is a variant of the tu quoque logical fallacy that attempts to discredit an opponent's position by charging them with hypocrisy without directly refuting or disproving their argument.

The classic example listed by the article is that of Soviet apologists who in defense of their regime's human rights violations would attack the US on the basis of historical slavery and Jim crow and point out that African-Americans in the US are currently still disproportionately poor and disadvantaged in many ways. Note that the history is irrelevant to the US indictment of Soviet abuses of human rights, and that despite the inequity in US society between black and whites statistically speaking, it is a brazen false equivalence with Soviet oppression of the individual. [Political repression in the former Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_repression_in_the_Soviet_Union) was fundamentally different than the systemic racism in the US in several important ways.

Let's do a quick example of bad reasoning drawn from the historical origins of whataboutism, in response to US criticism of human rights abuse, the argument may be made:

**P1** The US has in the past engaged in slavery, and therefore is hypocritical.
**P2** Anyone who engages in such hypocrisy regarding civil rights has no valid point in regards to our treatement of our citizens.
**C** Any and all criticisms therefore of our treatment from the US are not cogent.

Comment: Your premise one already has a conclusion?  We already have problems. Therefore is a conclusion indicator which means you have a premise displayed, a hidden premise & conclusion which is expressing the U.S. is hypocritical. Your use of the  hypocritical is not correct. Hypocrite is one who says one thing and DOES ANOTHER. In this case people could have learned from past mistakes. If they learn and are now consistent there is no hypocrisy. Premise to cannot stand as written for the use of hypocrisy is faulty. Thirdly, the conclusion has the term cogent in it? Cogent is not used for deduction.

Comment: The rules for rhetoric and deductive reasoning is just not the same. Rhetoric uses arguments to persuade whereas philosophy never does. It is more of an intellectual process. Deductive reasoning seeks to point out bad reasoning & if the fallacy has a NAME then it has a FORM WE RECOGNIZE. THAT IS HOW WE DETECT IT. How else would you know a fallacy occurred? Informal is not LITERAL. it means an argument or inferences are not categorical in context. We recognize fallacies because they have a repetitive form or repetitive properties we can measure. Hypocrisy is not acts years apart.

Comment: @Logikal You clearly have a command of the English language, but don't seem to see the forest for the trees. 1) The conclusion of an argument can be a premise of another. Strictly speaking, my argument isn't an atomistic syllogism. That doesn't mean it's not an argument. 2) Of course my use of hypocritical is not correct. That's why whataboutism is a fallacy. Please reread the post as you seem confused. The OP is asking about an informal fallacy used in argumentation. I'm not sure why you seem stuck on the idea that he is asking about a formal deduction. What is your first language?

Comment: Again, the user in no way indicated that he wanted an analysis according to strictly formal deduction. That is your bias.

Answer (score 0):

Affirming a disjunct: x or y; y, therefore not x.

And the fallacy of infallibility, which assumes that infallibility is possible and only those who are infallible have authority.  On the other hand, we have to be mindful of the fallacy of experience, that our personal experiences, which are anecdotal, may not reflect the experiences of others and represent definitive proof.

Answer (score -1):

The situation you describe reminds me of the *genetic fallacy*.

Someone commits the genetic fallacy when they assess a claim on the basis of facts about its source or origin rather than on its own merit.

For example: X told you that Y, and since X is not trustworthy, ~Y *must* be the case.

Explanation: X may not be trustworthy but that does not mean that the opposite of Y is necessarily the case. To fully assess someone's belief in Y, you cannot simply look at the source of their belief in order to discredit it.